# What policy were put into the place in order to prevent grossly insufficient oversight by the FAA to regulate Boeing?

Tags: united-states, regulation

> The report reveals several unmistakable facts. The MAX crashes were
> not the result of a singular failure, technical mistake, or mismanaged
> event. They were the horrific culmination of a series of faulty
> technical assumptions by Boeing’s engineers, a lack of transparency on
> the part of Boeing’s management, and grossly insufficient oversight by
> the FAA—the pernicious result of regulatory capture on the part of the
> FAA with respect to its responsibilities to perform robust oversight
> of Boeing and to ensure the safety of the flying public.

https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-Y4_T68_2-PURL-gpo144993/pdf/GOVPUB-Y4_T68_2-PURL-gpo144993.pdf

What policy were put into the place in order to prevent grossly insufficient oversight by the FAA to regulate Boeing? The MAX crashes were not the result of a singular failure. They were partly due to the grossly insufficient oversight by the FAA, which failed to regulate Boeing and ensure the safety of the flying public. I was wondering what policies were adopted by the U.S. to address this issue since then.

Comment: You seem to suggest that there were any. AFAIK the opposite is true - policies were put into place to prevent the FAA from performing oversight over Boeing effectively.

Comment: @littleadv are you saying that the policies have become **more** lax in the last 4 years or so?

Comment: Probably resumed enforcement where it had been lax, rather than new policy. Interesting Q. Perhaps smth in common with previous Q about regulatory capture.

Comment: @fyrepenguin maybe not in the last 4 years, but definitely in the last 20 years. Which is about the time it takes to develop and manufacture a new aircraft model

Comment: Right, @littleadv, and the question ends with “I was wondering what policies were adopted by the U.S. to address this issue since then.” By my reading, it’s asking about what has been done recently to change the lack of oversight you refer to. The question may need a little bit of clarity though

Comment: Worth noting that any FAA action or lack thereof is backstopped by the ability of people harmed by lack of maintenance to sue Boeing and airlines based upon very Plaintiff friendly laws, and that because this is possible that their insurance company also imposes additional discipline, as does pressure from Wall Street since this impacts its stock price.